# Grant Privileges on Production Database Throws "Error: tuple concurrently updated"

Tags: postgresql, permissions, amazon-rds, concurrency

I would like to grant read access to all tables in my schema

```
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO XXX;
```

While it works on our alpha environment, it fails with our production database:

> [XX000] ERROR: tuple concurrently updated

There are [some examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19382284/postgresql-error-tuple-concurrently-updated) how to solve regular queries, but when it comes to `GRANT` commands it is getting more difficult. According to [this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46397414/why-cant-i-execute-truncate-and-grant-statement-on-a-table-in-parallel) I understood that another connection is granting/revoking permissions at the same time, something I hardly believe.

Is there a way to identify these other connections? Or in general to circumvent concurrent access to pg_class (i guess)?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your exact Postgres version (`select version();` will tell you)

Comment: it's PostgreSQL 9.6.11

Comment: What is the difference between you alpha environment, and production?  Different PostgreSQL versions?  Different schemas?

Comment: No, that error means that you yourself are modifying the same table row twice in the same statement. Unless you have some event trigger that causes the error, I'd suspect a PostgreSQL bug. Can you come up with a reproducible test case? Another idea: is partitioning involved? Also, what is your PostgreSQL version?

Comment: the alpha and live environment are exactly the same, except for provisioned RAM, CPU and, of course, traffic. @jjanes

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe we use trigger functions (on beta and production) but no event triggers. A reproducible test case is challenging as it is not reproducible for me in the beta environment. There is no partitioning involved, but there is another important difference between live and production: beta is a single instance while production has a read slave: it is hosted in AWS RDS as [Multi Availability Zone](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/details/multi-az/?nc1=h_ls). Version: PostgreSQL 9.6.11
Let me know what i can do, or how I can create a test case.

Comment: btw, all i do is:

```
CREATE ROLE XXX;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO XXX;
```

Comment: another insights: if instead i use GRANT SELECT TABLE ...list of all tables... TO XXX, it works.

Comment: Oh, you didn't say it was Amazon RDS. If it cannot be reproduced with a copy of the database on real PostgreSQL, I'd assume it is either data corruption or an Amazon bug. Try to dump the database and restore it to another RDS instance. If the problem persists (but does not manifest on a copy on PostgreSQL), it is an Amazon bug. If the cloned instance doesn't exhibit the problem, it is most likely data corruption.